# How to match fonts?

Tags: fonts

I have two font(ttf) files, lets say A and B.Now, I have some new font, is there a way to find which font of A and B matches more with my new font ?
I am new to fonts.Sorry, if my question is stupid.Thank you

Comment: What does that mean exactly, "matches more"?

Comment: @deceze By more, I mean in terms of visual similarity. Font Matching websites (like www.whatfontis.com ) uses glyphs extracted from images uploaded by user to match with the glyphs of existing fonts and they present a list of matching fonts in a certain order.I guess my question is how to extract glyphs from font files and how to match them?

Comment: Many possible approaches... Render the same string in both fonts and use an image diff algorithm to find the relative similarity of the two images. That's a rather rough method though. The more sophisticated solution would compare the fonts glyph by glyph comparing their vector representations and diffing those.

Comment: unless you can quantify "match", no one can give a real answer to this. Two different fonts sharing glyphs is almost never the case, so you need a metric to determine "how close two glyphs are", which isn't even a metric for how close two *fonts* are, which are not just collections of glyphs, but also of script, positioning, and substitution rules, and quite a bit more. It's not that this is a "stupid question", it's not a question yet: you need to define the words you use so that we understand what they mean.